# Increasing the width of a code block in Jekyll

Tags: css, jekyll

I would like to increase the width of code blocks in my Jekyll blog i.e.:

```
{% highlight swift %}
print("This is a line of test code")
var x: Int = 5
{% endhighlight %}
```

Currently they are a little too narrow when viewed on an iPhone 6:

[image]

I have tried editing _site.scss with the following:

```
  .highlight {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

[image]

This results in the width being as desired however the code block is not centered. Similarly if I try:

```
  figure {
    width: 100%;
  }
```

I get the same result. The desired width but not centered. What am I doing wrong here? Any pointers greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `width: 100% !important;` or `display: block;` on figure

Comment: tried this. still not centered